# Android Spinner throws an exception

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have an activity that contains a TextView, a ListView and a Spinner.
The spinner contains 4 items. onCreate, the spinner is assigned with one of the values that matches the current activity.
When user clicks on another Item a new Intent must be started (a new activity with the same layout).
However, I get an error when I leave uncommented the code regarding the spinner.
My Activity works fine without the "implements OnItemSelectedListener" and the implementation of the event.

So my code for the spinner :

```
public class ViziteIeri extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
...

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_new_screen);
                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.liste_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)

        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+parent.getItemAtPosition(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast1.show();

        Intent i = null;
        if(parent.getItemIdAtPosition(pos) == 1) {
            i=new Intent(ViziteIeri.this, ViziteAzi.class);
        }
        if(parent.getItemIdAtPosition(pos) == 2) {
            i=new Intent(ViziteIeri.this, ViziteMaine.class);
        }
        if(parent.getItemIdAtPosition(pos) == 3) {
            i=new Intent(ViziteIeri.this, ViziteViitor.class);
        }
        startActivity(i);           

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?
Sorry for the previous code. I changed the name of the activity just for pasting reasons. Now they are fixed. In my real app, of course the activities are properly named, otherwise I could not run the app (right?)

@CodeMonkey - here is the error log:

```
`07-29 23:56:56.155: D/AndroidRuntime(2474): Shutting down VM
07-29 23:56:56.155: W/dalvikvm(2474): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1374)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at com.softwarex.mydualscreenpro.ViziteIeri.onItemSelected(ViziteIeri.java:89)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-29 23:56:56.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

I changed back the activity name because it became confusing. So the activity name is "ViziteIeri"
And again... if I let the event assignment uncommented, I cannot run the activity without receiving the above error stack

Comment: Error Description????

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Can you add your LogCat message to this answer to help with debugging?

Comment: Your activity is `myActivity` and you are using `ViziteIeri.this`? Why?

Comment: @wikram - sorry. I changed the name of the activity just for pasting the code here and probably missed one refference out. So that is not the problem

Comment: @CodeMonkey - I added the error log in the question body

Answer (score 0):

Because of your `Activity` Class name is `myActivity` so 
Use

```
i=new Intent(myActivity.this, ViziteAzi.class);
```

intead of

```
i=new Intent(ViziteIeri.this, ViziteAzi.class);
```

It will fix your `OnItemSelectedListener` problem.

Comment: Sorry again. I fixed the code in the question. And explained why it happened. ** this is not the real problem**. If that would have been the problem I would not be able to run the app. But that is not the case. So the problem lies somewhere else. Please reconsider and I apologize again for my misspelled code

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.
The solution is to set the Item in the spinner using:

```
spinner.setSelection(0,false);
```

before

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

That solved my problem. No more errors.
Thank you for your time.